# Restoring raid 0

Tags: macos, mac, raid, raid-0, hardware-raid

I have a Velocity Duo (PCI raid card) with two Samsung 850 drives (500gb ea) in a  RAID 0 setup in my Mac Pro.

The raid controller seemed to get scrambled and the drive is no longer accessible - Mac is not bootable.

However, using a raid recovery tool (ReclaiMe) I can access the RAID parameters and also the data (files and folders). I can export the data as an .img file.

The question is .. how do I restore this .img to a bootable drive?

I have a new 2TB drive at my disposal.

Should I store the .img file there and then reinitialize the RAID 0 setup on the existing Velocity Duo?

Other options?

Comment: Your raid card has failed you once and only by luck do you still have your data - are you sure, you want to try the same setup again?

Comment: nope..that's why I asked :)   Just need to get this mac booted up ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Put the .img in the new hard disk: img is the disk image. RAID is built above it, splitting img into 2 disks (RAID0).

I think this is enough (usually the img is left bootable).

If it doesn't boot. Check with OF, or check online about emergency disk (or a linux distribution) so that you can make the disk bootable.